# What happens to the custom attributes on records properties?

Tags: .net, .net-core, c#-9.0

I am unsuccessfully trying to get *custom attributes* of dotnet record properties through the Reflection API! I have annotated properties with a custom attribute, but as I can see in ILDASM no property, nor field, nor method member has that *custom attribute*. So, what has the compiler done with that annotation?

Simply try it `dotnet new classlib` and then create a `DummyAttribute` in the folder such as:

```cs
public class DummyAttribute : System.Attribute {}
```

Then replace `Class1` with:

```cs
public record Class1([Dummy] string Name){}
```

Finally, build it with `dotnet build` and check the generated `dll` in ILDASM. The property `Name` is missing the `DummyAttribute`, as you can observe next:

```
.property instance string Name()
{
  .get instance string app10_records_annotations.Class1::get_Name()
  .set instance void modreq([System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit) app10_records_annotations.Class1::set_Name(string)
} // end of property Class1::Name
```

What is happening with that annotation? can we annotate properties of dotnet records?

Comment: [Looks like you need to use `property:` or `field:` to show which member to apply the attribute to](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-9.0/records.md#properties)

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. A warning or compile error it would be nice. Dotnet documentation not even mention that behavior. Simply ignoring the annotation is not a nice feature!

Comment: @MiguelGamboa: It's not ignored - it ends up on the constructor parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute is applied to the constructor parameter by default. Here's the constructor in the IL:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor(string Name) cil managed
{
  .param [1]
  .custom instance void DummyAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       15 (0xf)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  stfld      string Class1::'<Name>k__BackingField'
  IL_0007:  ldarg.0
  IL_0008:  call       instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_000d:  nop
  IL_000e:  ret
} // end of method Class1::.ctor
```

As Damian noted, if you want the attribute applied to a field or property, [you use `property:` or `field:`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-9.0/records.md#properties). So your example would become:

```cs
public record Class1([property: Dummy] string Name){}
```

... at which point the property IL is generated as you'd expect:

```
.property instance string Name()
{
  .custom instance void DummyAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  .get instance string Class1::get_Name()
  .set instance void modreq([System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit) Class1::set_Name(string)
} // end of property Class1::Name
```

Comment: At least the MSDN documentation should describe that.